# Appcelerator, Android Emulator Build Speed Suggestions

Tags: android-emulator, runtime, titanium, appcelerator

So, attempting to figure out if there was a way to use the arguments in the runtime config I ran across my biggest runtime boast yet, calling the Appcelerator build script for the Android Emulator from the command-line, here's what I mean:

```
<full-path-to-python.exe> <full-path-2-.../android/builder.py> emulator <project-name> <android-sdk> <project-dir> <project-id> <avd-name>
```

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Appcelerator\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1331647813\python\python.exe" "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\builder.py" emulator JavaHomeBug "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk" "C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\JavaHomeBug" tld.domain.JavaHomeBug titanium_1_HVGA
```

Are there any other ways to get the emulator to load faster, including but not limited not executing anything but the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what your looking for but helps a lot with making changes and viewing them in the emulator.

Appcelerator implemented a festDev server. meaning that you can launch an app in the android emulator and leave it open, as you make changes to the code travel back through pages to make the page be reloaded and the new code will be pulled in.

For example going page 1 -> page 2,
then making a change on page 2,
click back button to go to page 1, now when go to page 2 you'll see your changes.

Takes a hige amount of time off waiting for the emulator to load up each time you change 1 or 2 lines

Comment: Awesome, because of you pointing that out, I found a [blog post by Appcelerator, Fastdev for Android](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/05/titanium-mobile-intro-series-fastdev-for-android.html). On a semi-unrelated note, there's a [proposed Appcelerator for Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40242/appcelerator). If you're interested in the idea, simply visit the page, review it, and click follow it. Cheers!